# How to use event source with a JSON format other than the default

Tags: json, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar with an event source that I don't control. This source doesn't return a JSON exactly as FullCalendar need and the events are "one level down" where they should be.

For example, the JSON returned by the feed would be something like:

```
{
    "sourcename": [
        {
            "start": "2016-04-18 14:00",
            "end": "2016-04-18 18:00",
            "title": "Working Group 1 meeting",
            "className": "wg",
            "url": "http://cnn.com/",
            "type": "restricted"
        },{
            "start": "2016-04-18 14:00",
            "end": "2016-04-18 18:00",
            "title": "Working Group 2 meeting",
            "className": "wg",
            "url": "http://cbsnews.com/",
            "type": "restricted"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any option on FullCalendar that allows to specify the "path" on the returned JSON or any other form to use such a event source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have no control over the feed, I'm guessing [*events as a function*](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/) is your only option.

This lets you control the request, but you need to send the parameters that would, otherwise, be appended automatically to the GET request (I'm talking about the `data` parameter).

On the AJAX request, just call the `callback` function (the 4th parameter on the function) with the events, which would be something like `data.sourcename`.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/fullcalendar/events17',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                start: start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                end: end.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
            },
            success: function(data) {
                callback(data.sourcename);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @milz!  this is exactly what I needed!